# NPM package is different from console log and misses directory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, package

I'm trying to create a npm package but the result is different of what the console displays.

It's a test library made with Vite and VueJS.

I have these folders: `.github`, `node_modules` and `src`. They're all in the same directy as the `package.json` file.
Whenever I run `npm run build`, it'll create a `dist` directory in the root folder containing `.js`-files as expected.

**The problem is:** Whenever my GitHub-Action is running, the published package does NOT include the `dist` directory.

Since I do not want the `dist` directory in the repository on GitHub itself, I've added it to the `.gitignore`. But if I do so, it's also not added to the final package when running `npm publish`.

I've also tested creating the `.npmignore` file with the same content as `.gitignore` but except the `dist` entry. Also, my `package.json` contains `dist` inside the `files` array.

The GitHub action output shows the correct log i guess:

```
npm notice 413B   dist/components/icons/vue-theme.es17.js    
npm notice 787B   dist/components/scaffolds/vue-theme.cjs.js 
npm notice 138B   dist/components/scaffolds/vue-theme.cjs2.js
npm notice 748B   dist/components/scaffolds/vue-theme.es.js  
npm notice 41B    dist/components/scaffolds/vue-theme.es2.js 
npm notice 10.9kB dist/index.css                             
npm notice 93B    dist/style.css                             
npm notice 1.6kB  dist/vue-theme.cjs.js                      
npm notice 1.7kB  dist/vue-theme.es.js                       
npm notice 1.4kB  package.json                               
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @mickedplay/vue-theme                   
npm notice version:       0.0.54                                  
npm notice filename:      mickedplay-vue-theme-0.0.54.tgz         
npm notice package size:  7.4 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 33.5 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        d8ec25fe08c650ae929702d9a5d8a4d52e866a16
npm notice integrity:     sha512-o2g4WiuIGhjdl[...]xn3kC5E8fKuuQ==
npm notice total files:   46                                      
npm notice 
npm notice Publishing to https://npm.pkg.github.com with tag latest and default access
+ @mickedplay/vue-theme@0.0.54
```

But whenever I install that package in another project using `"@mickedplay/vue-theme": "github:mickedplay/vue-theme"`, the directory inside of `node_modules` just contains two files: `README.md` and `package.json`. Thats all. No `dist` folder.

You can take a look at the test repository, it`'s public: https://github.com/mickedplay/vue-theme

Short summary: NPM package does not include `dist` directory even if provided to add.

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss something?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close, it's not reproducible, probably was fixed since then

Comment: No, it's not fixed. Still having this problem.

Comment: It's not reproducible. Try `npm init -y && npm add "github:mickedplay/vue-theme"` in a new project. There's `node_modules/@mickedplay/vue-theme/dist`. If the problem persists, clean npm cache, make sure you don't use old npm version that could behave in an odd way

Comment: It is reproducable. The "dist" folder that you can see is included in the Git repo. It's not the auto generated one which should be.

Comment: The question states there's no dist, so it's imprecise in this regard, because there's dist. What do you mean by auto generated? Generated by gh actions? It's published to gh registry and available through https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#installing-a-package .  dist should be commited to a repo in order to be installed with github: source, it basically clones a repo. In case this was your concern, that's it, these are two unrelated ways to add a package to dependencies

Comment: There's only a dist folder in the git because I#d run npm run build locally and pushed it. It's also running when github actions take care but the dist folder, that was built, is not included in the package.

Answer (score 0):

See
[npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-publish#files-included-in-package)

You can add:

```json
{
  "files": [
    "README.md",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

to `package.json` to specify the files to be included.

Comment: But thats exactly what I mean. Adding "dist" still does not include it.